# Does this game "Doomsday" have an alternate name?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]

This is a photo I found but when I search online for the name of that game I can't find anything online: no store, no product pages, no reviews, ... nothing.

Does the game has an alternate name or something?

Comment: What does the QR code resolve to?

Comment: Some deavianart picture not related at all to the game, i googled the red logo and still nothing

Comment: Could you give the actual QR code link?

Comment: On holiday, first Google hit with the name of the card game links to shops already like https://www.njuskalo.hr/drustvene-igre/doomsday-kartaska-igra-oglas-13632698

Comment: Njuškalo is croatian store like ebay, the game is sold maybe few years ago..

Comment: FYI, the QR code translates to `http://oprlet.daportfolio.com/` which in turn gives a 302 redirect to the top level Deviant Art page. But there is a Deviant Portfolio of the appropriate name: https://www.deviantart.com/oprlet

Answer (score 5):

As you can see on the box, the game is called "Doomsday ultimate playing cards game" . I found a [Croatian auction site selling one](https://www.njuskalo.hr/drustvene-igre/doomsday-kartaska-igra-oglas-13632698) with this image:

[image: Doomsday card game box]

The description there translates to:

> Doomsday is a fast and dynamic card game in which the goal is to collect the least number of card points and force your opponents to collect as many as possible. The number of players is limited by the amount of cards (a maximum of 8 per game is recommended), several game boxes can be combined to increase the number of players (e.g., 16 players with 2 boxes). The game is intended for players age 12 and up.
>
> The game is similar to Uno and Mao Mao.

I contacted the Author/ Seller and got the following reply:

> The game didn't change names or anything, it was made in just three
> limited batches in 2012 and 2013, and once more as a private order
> (100 pcs) by a company in 2014.

Comment: Current searches yield no results, so thanks for the answer.

Comment: Very, very stub BGG entry here https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/400234/doomsday

Comment: @PhilipKendall I saw that BGG listing as well but the description was actually less than already provided by the original selling store.